# Changing style on textview in a list view row when pressed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'd like to change the style of a textview in a list view row when that row is clicked. That text should remain focused until another row is pressed. I am using a subclass of BaseAdapter to build the row's in the list view. Would be great if I could get some help to make this happen.

This is part of my base adapter class.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MyHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.street_listrow, null);
        holder = new MyHolder();
        holder.txtViewStreet= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.StreetName);
        holder.txtViewArea = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.StreetArea);
        holder.txtViewDist = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.StreetDistance);
        holder.ivGo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.StreetGo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();;
    }

      holder.txtViewStreet.setText(street.get(position).getStreet());
      holder.txtViewArea.setText(street.get(position).getArea());
      holder.ivGo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goicon);
      int tempDist = Integer.parseInt(street.get(position).getDistance());
      if(tempDist>1000){
          Double bigDist = (double)tempDist / 1000;
          dist = df.format(bigDist) +" km";
      }else{
          dist = tempDist+" m";
      }
      holder.txtViewDist.setText(dist);
    return convertView;
}
```

I want txtViewStreet change color to green on the row that's clicked.

Basically:

Row1

Row2

Row3

*User press Row 2*

Row1

**Row2**

Row3

*User press Row 1*

**Row1**

Row2

Row3

Comment: Exactly what subclass of `BaseAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a field in your adapter class that will hold the current selected item:

```
int current = -1;
```

This position will be updated each time you click a row, in the `onItemClick()`:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        adapter.current = position;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

then in your `getView()` method:

```
//...
holder.txtViewStreet.setText(street.get(position).getStreet());
if (position == current) {
    holder.txtViewStreet.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    holder.txtViewStreet.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // or what is your default color
}
//...
```